# Simple Custom Pager in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview, pager

I am looking for the best way to implement a pager as per the following simple requirement.

I want a page like this

```
 <Pager 1 2 3 4 ...>

 <Partial View>
```

My action controller will look something like this...

```
    public PartialViewResult DisplayRecordDetails(int recordNumber)
    {
        MyRecord mr = GetRecord(recordNumber);
        return PartialView(mr);
    }
```

When I click on "1" (page index = 1), I pass 1 as a parameter to the DisplayRecordDetails action method and load the partial view with record 1.

When I click on "2" (page index = 2), I pass 2 as a parameter to the DisplayRecordDetails  action method and load the partial view with record 2 and so on...

I will have the total item count info and current page index info at my disposal. Now how can I generate the pager dynamically with this info?

I have tried searching for pager libraries/helpers but all of them are for grids. How can I use them for my situation? I do not have a grid. I just have a partial view which I need to load dynamically depending on the page number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could design a view model which will contain all the id numbers:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    // the currently selected id
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // a list of available ids
    public int[] Ids { get; set; }
}
```

And then have a controller action which will query your database or whatever and fetch the list of all available ids:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        Id = id ?? 0,
        Ids = new[] { 563, 845, 845 } // those will come from your datasource
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and in the corresponding view you could loop through those ids and generate links:

```
@model MyViewModel
<div>
    @Html.Action("DisplayRecordDetails", new { recordNumber = Model.Id })
</div>
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Ids.Length; i++) 
{
    <span>@Html.ActionLink((i + 1).ToString(), "Index", new { id = i })</span>
}
```

Comment: Thanks Darin. That's a pretty good solution for small number of pages. Now I am left with worrying about the appearance of the pager if I have a long range. Any tricks for 'Next' and 'Previous' functionality?

Comment: I just found a simple jQuery plugin that I can use.

http://blog.ajaxmasters.com/jquery-pagination-plugin/

I just set the items per page = 1, and it works like a charm...